Problem with importing TSV file to Microsoft SQL (System.OutOfMemoryException)
I'm trying to import some *.tsv files to Microsoft SQL Server database. To be more precise, I'm trying to import the IMDb Datasets.
In the SQL Server Management Studio I've tried to

right click my database > Tasks > Import Flat File...

When tried to import title.ratings.tsv like this, it worked. But when I tried to import name.basics.tsv, it failed with error:

TITLE: Import Flat File
An error occurred while running learn on the input file.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (mscorlib)

The name.basics.tsv is much larger (806 882 kB) than the title.ratings.tsv (24 230 kB), so I suppose that is causing the problem.
I have already tried to increase the SET_TEXTSIZE (*2, then tried *4) as it was suggested in this answer, however it seems the SQL Server Management Studio won't let me increase the number any further (it returned it to the same value as before).
Is there a way how to comfortably import a large *.tsv files (such as name.basics.tsv) into Microsoft SQL Server database? (Preferably without creating CREATE TABLE scripts where we would have to specify the schema, types. Because by using the mentioned method we wouldn't have to.)

Have you tried using a BULK INSERT instead?

I think I have tried it, but it required the tables to be already created. However I would like to avoid "CREATE TABLE scripts". I would like to know whether it is possible to do it more comfortably (without defining column types).

If you're not "comfortable" CREATEing tables, the  that's the real problem. Learn the syntax and get comfortable creating them.

There exists a way of importing data without creating tables using code. I've discovered the weakness of such a method and that is data quantity. I'm simply asking if there's a way of how to overcome this weakness. Ofc I could try to write a script that'd import data and that'd probably got the work done BUT simply clicking few buttons is faster (and yes, also more comfortable, I guess nobody can deny that), so imo more suitable when you just want to try/test something quickly. So even though you're probably right and I could do it using code, I'm still curious about the option without code.

Use the more complex, but more scalable "Import Data..." wizard instead of the "Import Flat File".  It's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16
You'll want to use the .NET Framework connector for SQL Server as the destination, and you'll probably want to use Integrated Security and Trust Server Certificate.  And all the columns in that file should be loaded into varchar(200) columns.

I downloaded the file and used the import wizard to load it into a local SQL Server instance (which I assume is his scenario).  The wizard suggests INT for some columns that contain non-numeric data.

Thank you for the tip. This seems like it should work, but it didn't (at least for me :/). I was doing something wrong probably. In the end I wrote scripts (for creating and inserting data) manually. And then I had problems even with the scripts :-D this blog post helped: https://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/bulk-insert-data-where-the
